# Mi base de datos me permite guardar calificaciones distintas de una misma asignatura en un mismo período

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tengo otra duda en relación a base de datos. Tengo la siguiente base de datos relacional para control de calificaciones. Sin embargo, en la tabla AsignaturaPeriodo tengo un problema, y es que **me está permitiendo colocar calificaciones distintas** para una misma asignatura durante un mismo período, pero **cuando las mismas tienen secciones diferentes**. Es decir, tengo a Pedro Pérez, al cual para el período 2018-01 le puedo colocar 60 y 70 puntos en las secciones 01 y 02 de Matemáticas, respectivamente. Esto es incorrecto, dado que para un período sólo puedo tener una calificación para una materia y debo cursarla sólo en una sección durante dicho período.

Les dejo el modelo relacional que hice a ver si pueden ayudarme en la detección del error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano muchas graciassssss!!!

Answer (score 0):

Agrega como llave primaria compuesta los campos respectivos. En AsignaturaPeriodo serían las 3 primeras y la cédula del estudiante.
Igual agrega pk en carreraEstudiante y pensumEstudios.
En sí, em primary key (pk) o llave primaria agregan el constraint o restricción unique. Que no permite que ésta se repita.

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste @Jocksan Cruz, pero no se si me faltó algo porque todo sigue igual. Te muestro la definición que hice de las tablas en el próximo comentario.

Comment: Marca el check de UQ, asumiría que es el del constraint Unique.

Answer (score 0):

Hice lo que me dijiste @Jocksan Cruz, pero no se si me faltó algo porque todo sigue igual. Te muestro la definición que hice de las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdona, mi error, asumí que my_sql agregaría el constraint Unique automáticamente, pero hay que indicarlo, ejemplo: "CREATE TABLE `content_html` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_box_elements` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_router` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_czech_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_box_elements` (`id_box_elements`,`id_router`)
);"

Comment: Por favor si agregaras más información edita tu pregunta, no publiques una respuesta.